# MySQL Count Records Based On Criteria Within A Group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing the following data columns:

```
ord_number check
OR123      0
OR125      1
OR123      2
OR123      0
OR124      0
OR124      0
OR125      0
OR123      0
```

The check column indicates if we have fully supplied the order line with a value of zero or below meaning 'yes we have supplied complete' and a value of 1 or above meaning 'no we have not supplied complete' .

To calculate an order fill rate (how many orders have been filled complete) I need to know how many of the orders have only zero check results for each entry and how many have at least one positive check result.

My logic is that I need to GROUP the items and then carry out a COUNTIF within the group (this may be the wrong SQL methodology but logically it makes sense to me in terms of the outcome I'm looking for). From this query I need to return those two values into my PHP script.

The results from this data set would be:
Complete = 1 (orders with only zero checks)
Incomplete = 2 (orders where one or more lines have positive checks)

I've spent the morning trying to find a solution but can't find anything that I either understand enough or is similar enough that I can break it down and understand it.

If someone can help me by pointing me in the right direction or can provide a sample with an explanation I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 row with 2 counter fields use:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN `check` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `check` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete
FROM orders
```

For 2 rows with 1 name use:

```
 SELECT COUNT(`ord_number`) AS fulfillment 
 FROM orders WHERE (`check`=0) 
 UNION SELECT COUNT(ord_number) 
 FROM orders WHERE (`check`=1)
```

in which case you need to put row 1 into $complete (check=0) 
and row 2 into $incomplete (check=1)

you may add:

```
 UNION SELECT COUNT(ord_number) FROM orders
```

which will give you the total records on row 3.

output will be:

```
 SELECT * FROM orders

 ord_number  check
 ---------------------
 OR123        0
 OR124        1
 OR125        0
 OR126        0
 OR127        0
 OR123        0
 OR125        1


SELECT COUNT(`ord_number`) AS counts FROM orders or1 WHERE (`check`=0) 
UNION SELECT COUNT(ord_number) FROM orders or2 WHERE (`check`=1) 
UNION SELECT COUNT(ord_number) FROM orders

 counts
 -------
 5
 2
 7


 SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN `check` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN `check` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete FROM orders

 incomplete complete
 -------------------------
  2         5
```

### As for PHP:

for 1 row:

```
mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
$query_countIn1Row = " SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `check` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  
    incomplete, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `check` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete
FROM orders";
$countIn1Row = mysql_query($query_countIn1Row, $test) or die(mysql_error());

do {
    $varIncomplete = $row_countIn1Row['incomplete'];
    $varComplete = $row_countIn1Row['complete'];
} while ($row_countIn1Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countIn1Row));
```

and for 1 column with counts:

```
mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
$query_countOrders = "SELECT COUNT(`ord_number`) AS counts 
FROM orders or1 WHERE (`check`=0) 
UNION SELECT COUNT(ord_number) FROM orders or2 WHERE (`check`=1)
UNION SELECT COUNT(ord_number) FROM orders";
$countOrders = mysql_query($query_countOrders, $test) or die(mysql_error());

$myCounts = array();
 do {
    $myCounts[]= $row_countOrders['counts'];
 } while ($row_countOrders = mysql_fetch_assoc($countOrders));
 $complete = $myCounts[0];
 $incomplete = $myCounts[1];
 $total = $myCounts[2];
```

Comment: Hi Gal, thanks for our help I'm getting somewhere with this query just trying to get it to output in PHP

Comment: strSQL = "Put the Query here";

Comment: Hi Gal, the original SQL was good I thin kit's just my PHP skills that are causing the problem here. Will the Sum options you've now added still group by ord_number?

Comment: what is the PHP problem then ? The SQL is just counting complete and incomplete...

Comment: do you have same order IDs repeating in the table of orders ?

Comment: I need to store the results into variables so that I can do some further calculations. See edit to main post with output - does that make sense?

Comment: I've added sample PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**SELECT `ord_number`,IF(MAX( `check`) <=0 ,'COMPLETED','PENDING') 
from `TABLENAME`
 group by (`ord_number` )**

Through this  oneline query you will easily get which order is in pending status and which one is complete status

AS per your given details

> The check column indicates if we have fully supplied the order line
>   with a value of zero or below meaning 'yes we have supplied complete'
>   and a value of 1 or above meaning 'no we have not supplied complete' .

it means check column can contain  negative value as well as  0 for indicating the complete status and 1 or any postive integer number to indicate the pending status.

so the logic should be find the max(check) so if the max for a order is found 0 or any negative number then we will sure that order is complete and if it found a positive number it means  there was a pending   entry.

Comment: Very clever logic John although I can't get this to work. Can you help me further by explaining why there are quotes around the completed and pending - I ask as they are causing me parsing issues once embedded in PHP.

Comment: @Gebraffe i have edited the query ,it will work with the modified one also. now check at your end

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

```sql
SELECT ord_number,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `check` =  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Comp,
       COUNT(`check`) as total
FROM tab1
GROUP BY ord_number
```

This would give you the number of rows with 0 (complete) and the total number of rows for each ord_number.

Then you do a COUNT to validate when those two are equal:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN comp = total THEN 'COMPLETE' ELSE 'INCOMPLETE' END AS status,
       COUNT(*) AS statusCount
FROM(
   SELECT ord_number,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `check` =  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Comp,
       COUNT(`check`) as total
   FROM tab1
   GROUP BY ord_number) a
GROUP BY 1;
```

This should get you what you want.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a12e86/7)</kbd>

Note that i used `` ` `` around check since this is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Comment: Hi Filipe, thank you for your help. That's making some sense but how do I embed this within my PHP code so that I can get the data returned into a variable or array? Usually I would use the $result = mysql_query(.... and then pull the data from the $result? Sorry if these seems like a basic question.

Comment: I'm not very fluent in php, sorry, but you will get two rows in php, each one has a status and a statusCount.

Comment: @Gebraffe. No problem. If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.